# Audio recording failed when I use linphone sdk

Tags: ios, audio, record, voip, linphone

I am developing VOIP application using linphone on IOS.

I used [[LinphoneManager instance] startLibLinphone] function for linphone sdk initialization.

And then I used below code for audio recording.

But I got recording failed error.

How can I record audio using linphone sdk?

Thank you.

```
NSError *error;

// Recording settings
NSDictionary *settings = @{AVEncoderAudioQualityKey: @(AVAudioQualityMedium),
                                 AVFormatIDKey: @(kAudioFormatMPEG4AAC),
                                 AVEncoderBitRateKey: @(128000),
                                 AVNumberOfChannelsKey: @(1),
                                 AVSampleRateKey: @(44100),
                            AVLinearPCMBitDepthKey:@(8)};

// File URL
NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:pathToSave];//FILEPATH];

// Create recorder
recorder = [[AVAudioRecorder alloc] initWithURL:url settings:settings error:&error];
if (!recorder)
{
    NSLog(@"Error establishing recorder: %@", error.localizedFailureReason);
    return NO;
}

recorder.delegate = delegate;
recorder.meteringEnabled = YES;

if (![recorder prepareToRecord])
{
    NSLog(@"Error: Prepare to record failed");
    return NO;
}

if (![recorder record])
{
    NSLog(@"Error: Record failed");
    return NO;
}
```

Comment: What is the exact error that you are getting?

Comment: I got error at below code.   if (![recorder record])
{
    NSLog(@"Error: Record failed");
    return NO;
}

Comment: I solved this problem. I added below code. AVAudioSession *audioSession = [AVAudioSession sharedInstance];
NSError *err = nil;
[audioSession setCategory :AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayAndRecord error:&err];
if(err){
    NSLog(@"audioSession: %@ %d %@", [err domain], [err code], [[err userInfo] description]);
    return;
}
[audioSession setActive:YES error:&err];

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem.

I added below code.

```
AVAudioSession *audioSession = [AVAudioSession sharedInstance];
NSError *err = nil;
[audioSession setCategory :AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayAndRecord error:&err];
if(err){
   NSLog(@"audioSession: %@ %d %@", [err domain], [err code], [[err userInfo] description]);
return;
}
[audioSession setActive:YES error:&err];
```

So it works well.